# Set actual height for input

Tags: html, css

So I have this input:

```
 <input type="number" class="inv_1"/>
```

And I try to set height:

```
.inv_1 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 32px;
}
```

What I expected: an input tag with 32px height.
What I got: an input tag with 38px height.

I set it at 26px now, so I get 32px.
The question is, can I set actual height? I want that element have the same height as in CSS. Just like divs and buttons which somehow have 32px with that class.

*I wish CSS had "actual" properties. For example: "actualheight: 32px" and it's 32px. Same for width, text align, borders, padding, etc. Imagine how cool it is, to get what you wanted, not what you need to fight with.*

**(UPD: thanks for answers, works perfectly with box-sizing: border-box. Unfortunately I can only "accept" one answer)**

Comment: You need to look at your textbox in the browser dev tools, another more global style for input fields may be overriding yours as the code you have shared worked as it should when dropped into JsFiddle. Meaning the height matches what is specified in the CSS in this case 32px.

Comment: @Kyle you miss the obvios issue. The default padding and border behavior. The 32px are not taking that into account. He needs to simply use `box-sizing: border-box;` instead of the default `content-box` or remove the default border and padding.  There is nothing wrong with the CSS or oevrwriting the styling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the [box-model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model) property `box-sizing` to `border-box`. Your height "inconsistency" is due to the default box model of "content-box".

```css
.inv_1 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 32px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" class="inv_1"/>
```

With `content-box`, padding, borders, and height/width (content) are calculated additively.

With `border-box`, padding and borders are included in height/width calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the default broder and padding. Use `box-sizing: border-box;` as in the snippert below. And input is an empty tag. It needs no closing slash.

```css
input {
  display: inline;
}

.inv_1 {
  width: 30%;
  height: 32px;
}

.inv_2 {
  width: 30%;
  height: 32px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" class="inv_1">
<input type="number" class="inv_2">
```